# How can I define and call cucumber steps/scenarios outside of the cucumber cli?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have a working cucumber setup. My `features/` folder has feature and step definitions, and I can call `cucumber` at the command line to run the test suite.

I also have a separate script which I would like to enable to call some of the cucumber tests. I know that in a cucumber step definition, it's possible to call a step from another step. But I don't know a way to:

- require my feature files
- require my step files
- and run some series of feature/scenario/steps.

From the [relishApp cucumber api docs](https://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/api), I've gathered this:

```
require 'cucumber'

# run all features
runtime = Cucumber::Runtime.new
Cucumber::Cli::Main.new([]).execute!(runtime)
```

This will run all my cucumber tests in the exact same way as if I has run `cucumber` from the command line, formatting included. However, I'm not sure how use this approach to:

- run a specific feature or step
- continue to the rest of the script ( because `execute!` exits the program).

I've also been looking at the cucumber source code to try and write/invoke steps dynamically:

```
require 'cucumber'

Given(/foo/) {}
# this raises an error:
# NoMethodError: undefined method `register_rb_step_definition'
# for Cucumber::RbSupport::RbLanguage:Class
# from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber/2.4.0/lib
#       /cucumber/rb_support/rb_dsl.rb:28
# :in `register_rb_step_definition

# A way to make `'register_rb_step_definition'` succeed:
runtime = Cucumber::Runtime.new
config = Cucumber::Configuration.new
language = Cucumber::RbSupport::RbLanguage.new(runtime, config)
dsl = Cucumber::RbSupport::RbDsl
dsl.rb_language = language
steps = {}
steps["foo"] = dsl.register_rb_step_definiton(/foo (.+)/, ->(args) { puts args })

# Now I have a 'steps' hash like {"foo" => foo_step_object}
# I can call a step like so:
steps["foo"].invoke(["bar"]) # the argument to invoke is an array or hash
# this will print bar to the console like the step proc instructed
```

This defines and invokes tests successfully, but there are a few shortcomings:

- It's necessary to separate out step name and argument. I would ideally like to be able to call something like `step("foo bar")` instead of writing `steps["foo"].invoke(["bar"])`. With my current attempt to invoke steps, the regex in the definitions is ignored.
- It'd be nice if the CLI output formatters were used.

I've been looking at some discussion about Cucumber and it seems there's a push to remove the capability to call a step using the `steps` method. In other words, all step nesting should be done through refactoring the code into separate methods, not by referencing other steps. I understand the inspiration for this notion, but I still envision a use-case for:

- defining regex matchers at the global scope
- providing a string, finding the regex match, and executing the step
- use formatters for output

This is basically how Cucumber works already if it's run with the `cucumber` shell command, although it requires all steps to be run within a feature & scenario. If my application only needs 'steps', but needs to define a global 'feature' and 'scenario', so be it, but I'd still like to use Ruby only and not divert to the `cucumber` shell command.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want the overhead of cucumber without the benefit of feature files. You can write functions, that your steps can call if you still want steps, then you can call those functions from a script or IRB or PRY.

Comment: Say I have a whole test suite built into Cucumber (not in separate functions). All the actual code is contained in the step definitions, which are called by the "features". I'm trying to call my steps by defining features on-the-fly. I am sure it's possible, but I've been digging around the [cucumber-ruby](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/index) source and can't figure it out.

Comment: In the meantime I've made a gem to help do this, it's called [hackney](https://github.com/maxpleaner/hackney). Though I'm still curious if it can be done with just cucumber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of what works for me, defining and invoking steps manually:

```
require 'cucumber' # must require everything; otherwise Configuration cannot be initialized

config = Cucumber::Configuration.new
dsl = Object.new.extend(Cucumber::RbSupport::RbDsl)
rb_language = Cucumber::RbSupport::RbLanguage.new(:unused, config)
step_search = Cucumber::StepMatchSearch.new(rb_language.method(:step_matches), config)

dsl.Given(/hello (.*)/) { |foo| puts "argument given was: #{foo}" }

match = step_search.call('hello world').first
match.step_definition.invoke(match.args) # => argument given was: world
```

It will raise exceptions for redundant or ambiguous step definitions, too:

```
dsl.Given(/hello (.*)/) {  }
dsl.Given(/(.*) world/) {  }
step_search.call('hello world')
# => Cucumber::Ambiguous: Ambiguous match of "hello world"
```

If you intend to also have actual feature files or step definition files around but don't want them to be included, then have in mind that initialising `Configuration` without any parameters will autoload some folders:

```
config = Cucumber::Configuration.new
config.autoload_code_paths
# => ["features/support", "features/step_definitions"]

config = Cucumber::Configuration.new(autoload_code_paths: [])
config.autoload_code_paths
# => []
```

Comment: it seems that i was 75% of the way there. this is a quite comprehensive answer so i'll accept it. thanks!

Comment: Yes, you were only really missing the `StepMatchSearch`. Good work; and a pity that this is not documented better. Spent almost a day researching and reverse-engineering this from their specs.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is

```
require 'cucumber'
require 'path_to_step_defs.rb'
```

What this does is load the file `path_to_step_defs.rb` once, and only once. Then you don't need the `load_step_definitions` method, because the script file has already loaded what it needs.

Comment: Say I write `require 'cucumber'; Given(/foo/) { }` - this raises an error `undefined method 'register_rb_step_definition' for nil:NilClass
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_dsl.rb:27:in 'register_rb_step_definition'`

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't define a step definition with an empty regex (what the heck would the point be?)

Comment: It's the same effect with text in there

Comment: Right, you've written it wrong. The correct syntax is `Given /some_regex/ do ... end`.

Comment: what i'm saying is adding text in the regex doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: But you've used the wrong syntax. That's why you're getting the error, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I pasted it a few comments back.

Comment: Ok, I already tried that. That what I meant, a few comments back, by "its the same effect with text in there"

Comment: Then I'm really not sure what the issue is. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118115/discussion-between-sebastian-lenartowicz-and-max-pleaner).